# Find those rows with only one value in another column?

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
column1          column2 (varchar)
--------------------------
foobar           0
foobar           1
whatever         0
whatever         0
whatever         0
```

What I want is to get all those values from column1 that have only zeros in column 2. In this case I only want "whatever", because "foobar" has values 0 and 1. I tried with a join, but failed. How could I solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your table appears to have no PRIMARY KEY. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(column2)
       FROM table1 t2
       WHERE t2.column1=t1.column1
       GROUP BY column1) = 0
--GROUP BY column1
```

if you want only one row as result uncomment last row

Comment: I cant use sum, the column2 column is varchar.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks! How would I find those having only 1 in column2? I cant use sum here I guess...

Comment: hmmm - you only want foobar if all columns are 1? then try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15e00/1

Comment: I want those values from column1 that only have 1 in column2. In my example, it would return nothing. If the first 0 for foobar was 1, too, it should return foobar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way:

```
select column1
from table t
group by column1
having sum(column2 <> '0') = 0;
```

That is, count the number of values in column2 that are not `0`.  And make sure there are no such rows.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using join over subquery which often gives better result

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2
 ON t2.column1=t1.column1
-- GROUP BY column1
```